# How to update a grid in a listbox with more rows and columns dynamically and programmatically in code (C# and WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, grid, dynamically-generated

I have a ListBox where every of its item has a DataTemplate to define its structure. It initially has a Grid that contains 6 rows and 4 columns. But then during runtime I want to add to a specific ListBoxItem more rows and columns to that Grid in that DataTemplate. How do I do that? Do I need to create a new DataTemplate that contains the Grid with added rows and columns? I have seen so much examples that looks like what I want to achieve that got confused right now with all the Bindings, ObservableCollections, ViewModel and so on. What should I do? Here is the WPF code below for that specific ListBox:

```
    <ListBox Margin="0,138,28.58,156" Name="list" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="387.235" SelectionChanged="list_SelectionChanged">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                </Grid>

            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is another op asking similar question. You could take a look at his question. His question is actually your answer.

He uses a custom control that derivates from Grid and he calls it Board. Futhermore he adds rows and columns at run-time which seems exactly what you would like to achive.

Here is the link:
[wpf MouseMove-Event in Board class does not work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16122896/wpf-mousemove-event-in-board-class-does-not-work)

Comment: Yeah that did work, I removed the DataTemplate and the ItemTemplate tags and I created a ListBoxItem which would contain a created Grid by assigning its content:

Comment: ListBoxItem lbItem = new ListBoxItem();
lbItem.Content = myGrid;
this.list.Items.Add(lbItem);

This ListBoxItem contains the Grid myGrid and this myGrid now contains data on several rows and columns. How do I then access this grid and update the data on a specific row and column?

Comment: Could I also use a DataTemplate Selector to decide the dynamic content of a ListBoxItem? I have noticed that a ListBoxItem that contains a specific grid structure in a ListBox cannot be added to another ListBox but instead I receive the XamlParseException. Maybe I would then write my own copy function?

Comment: Alright it worked with using VisualTreeHelper to create dynamic grids of a ListBoxItem. 

Now I have inserted a Button in every item programmatically and a specific button is intended to show more information based on the specific item the button was pressed from. How do I bind the button with the item when is pressed during the event handler? 

Another idea I have with the button is that when an item is not selected it will not be enabled. But when an item is selected then the button will be enabled. Can I somehow use the VisualTreeHelper to gain access to the button and change its status?

Comment: I solved it also, again it was to use the VisualTreeHelper but by finding the parent of the button, which is represented by the parameter sender in the button click event. I could then obtain the listboxitem the button belonged to and perform the desired operation.